# Best practice to close WCF Clients after async calls

Tags: wcf, asynchronous, proxy, client

Can anybody advice me the best practice for closing WCF clients after doing a async calls? Should it be within the  "completed" method or should there be a different approach?

/BB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good practice to close the client in the EndOperation() method.

--larsw